# Downvoted an answer and MY score went down

Tags: support, voting

I'm trying to figure out why when I downvoted an answer, my score went down as well. I don't see anywhere why that should affect my score.

Comment: Downvotes _on answers_ cost reputation to deter abuse. Downvotes on questions are free.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's how the reputation system works, as you can read [on our FAQ](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation); specifically:

> [reputation effect when] answer is voted down  -2  (-1 to voter)

This is the way it works across the entire Stack Exchange network. As for **why** that is how reputation works across the network, you should check out [this meta-discussion on the network's main meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15863/why-do-you-lose-reputation-for-down-voting).

Comment: Thank you @Oak, I didn't see that in the FAQ before I must have missed it.